# Conexão Php MySQL PDO em localhost pelo ip

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho um sistema PHP/MySQL em que conecto via PDO no host "localhost", mas vou precisar colocar o IP do servidor "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" ao invés do "localhost", o sistema funciona mas muito lento. Não sei o que pode ser, tanto o apache quanto o MySQL estão na mesma maquina. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Deixa eu tentar entender, nesse caso o teste de velocidade está sendo feito localmente, ou em um servidor externo?

Comment: Estou testando externamente, mas a diferença de velocidade é perceptível. Fiz um teste agora e localmente não há diferença de velocidade.

Comment: Pq daí, tem de ver a conexão, o serviço de hospedagem, se tá rolando legal em casa...

Comment: Está em um servidor próprio que montei, ai o ip local dele está tipo 192.168.1.15 ai no pdo eu passo esse ip pra conectar ao inves de localhost. Funciona mas lento demais

Comment: Certo, mas qual é sua conexão com ele, que tipo de cabo tá usando...E a conf do server, a cpu, a placa de rede.....Tem de por tudo tim tim por tim tim, pra poder avaliar.... A configuração, o SO...QQ que falar é um tiro no escuro...Pode acertar um inocente...;)

Comment: Tipo assim dependendo do cabo que se tá usando a placa até corrige, mas ai já vai um tempinho... Isso é uma das possibilidades....

Comment: A consulta ao BD vai ser mais rápido local porque os dois serviços estão trabalhando na mesma máquia. Na minha opinião, acho que o problema não esta na modo que esta fazendo a conexão do sistema com o banco, e sim no seu servidor de bando de dados. Aconselho você adicionar/trocar as TAG para algo que seja mais relacionado com servidor.

Comment: Como estão na mesma maquina vc nao prefere conectar va socket?

Comment: Acho que não ficou claro. O Apache e MySQL estão na mesma maquina. O Php conecta localhost, o ip desta mesma maquina é 192.168.1.15. Mudei a configuração ao inves de informar "localhost" para o PDO estou informando o IP 192.168.1.15 que é do proprio "localhost". Mas ai fica lento. So estou com uma maquina, não tem outro serrvidor. Ficou claro?

Comment: Estou fazendo a conexão assim:
.
`new PDO($this->dbType.":host=localhost;dbname=".$_SESSION['cliente'], $this->user, $this->senha ...`
.
Ai mudei para:
.
`new PDO($this->dbType.":host=192.168.1.15;dbname=".$_SESSION['cliente'], $this->user, $this->senha, ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema.

Nas configurações do MySQL adicionei:

```
skip-name-resolve
```

Fica ai pra quem precisar